# Can't display an initial value for input type number in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with my code. I am displaying the data from my database and load it in my view. All the fields are working they have the correct value for the inputs. But in one of my input field I can't display the value from my database.

here's some of my code:

My form input

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Set(%): </label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-right" ng-model="quotelist.vat_rate" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a JS like this:

```
//CALL OUR MODULE AND LOAD SOME MODULES
var quotationList = angular.module('quotation_list', ['jsonFormatter','ui.bootstrap','ckeditor']);

quotationList.controller('quoteListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

var quoteList = this;

//initialize value for header
quoteList.receiver = "<?php echo $quotation['receiver_name']; ?>";
quoteList.reference_no = <?php echo $quotation['reference_no']; ?>;
quoteList.address = "<?php echo $quotation['address']; ?>";
quoteList.project_name = "<?php echo $quotation['project_name']; ?>";
quoteList.vat_rate = <?php echo $totals['vat_rate']; ?>; //HERES MY PROBLEM. IN MY DATABASE RESULT IT SHOULD BE 12 BUT I CAN'T DISPLAY IT IN THE FORM INPUT
```

I tried to remove the ng-model in the input and print the value directly to the form input and it display.

Here's what I did:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Set(%): </label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control text-right" value="<?php echo $totals['vat_rate']; ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know where's my error. I am still new with angular.

Comment: your variables should be defined on the $scope to make them visible to your view, as in $scope.quoteList.vat_rate = <?php echo $totals['vat_rate']; ?>;

Comment: I have an alias in my controller declaration like this `<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="quoteListCtrl as quotelist">`

Comment: if you do console.log(quoteList.vat_rate) what do you get?

Comment: I got the result which is `12`

Comment: try removing var quoteList = this; and define all your variables on the $scope also remove ng-controller="quoteListCtrl as quotelist"> and just leave ng-controller="quoteListCtr">

Comment: Is $totals['var_rate'] a valid integer or a string? Try using `parseFloat(<?php echo $totals['vat_rate']; ?>);`

Comment: I think it will work if I do that but I have a nested controller in my form. And if I do that it might have some conflicts in some of my models. But I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your variable like so:

```
//CALL OUR MODULE AND LOAD SOME MODULES
var quotationList = angular.module('quotation_list', ['jsonFormatter','ui.bootstrap','ckeditor']);

quotationList.controller('quoteListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.quoteList = {}; 

//initialize value for header
$scope.quoteList.receiver = "<?php echo $quotation['receiver_name']; ?>";
$scope.quoteList.reference_no = <?php echo $quotation['reference_no']; ?>;
$scope.quoteList.address = "<?php echo $quotation['address']; ?>";
$scope.quoteList.project_name = "<?php echo $quotation['project_name']; ?>";
$scope.quoteList.vat_rate = <?php echo $totals['vat_rate']; ?>; //HERES MY PROBLEM. IN MY DATABASE RESULT IT SHOULD BE 12 BUT I CAN'T DISPLAY IT IN THE FORM INPUT
```

in your view then:

```
ng-controller="quoteListCtrl"
```

Comment: I got an error: `Error: $scope.quoteList is undefined`

Comment: $scope.quoteList = {}; and then your code. Leran how to use objects literals.

Comment: @Jax, the OP stated that they are using the *controller as* syntax.  This is the preferred syntax since version 1.2.

Comment: Ok I managed to solved it. Somewhere in my code I have a second declaration for the quoteList.vat_rate that's why I always get 0. And when I removed the second declaration it shows. Sorry for some misunderstanding and for my fault also. Thanks for the suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Jax has mentioned, you would need to use `$scope` within your controller to bind your data with the web view.

So bind your data by using $scope in your controller view:

```
$scope.quoteList.vat_rate = quoteList.vat_rate;
```

And bind this to your web view:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control text-right" ng-model="quotelist.vat_rate" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still the output I got is 0

Comment: Make sure your "12" is a number, not a string. Try setting the input type = "" for your form input and see whether you see it on your web view

Comment: @DanielChan, actually, OP stated that they are using the *controller as* syntax.  This is actually the preferred syntax since version 1.2.

Comment: Ok I managed to solved it. Somewhere in my code I have a second declaration for the `quoteList.vat_rate` that's why I always get `0`. And when I removed the second declaration it shows. Sorry for some misunderstanding and for my fault also. Thanks for the suggestions. :)